# Sqlite and nested query in the from statement

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am currently working with SQLite and I am freaking out with this query

```
    SELECT Cur.Name, SUM(Cur.Added+Cur.Removed) AS Lines, COUNT(DISTINCT(Cur.Author)) AS authCurrent,
       ( SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(Author)) 
         FROM Change
         WHERE Extencion = "java" AND
             Date >= date('2012-04-08') AND
             Date < date('2012-04-15')
         ) AS totCurrent
    FROM 
       Change AS Cur,
       ( SELECT a.Name, COUNT(DISTICT(a.Author)) AS authLast
         FROM Change AS a
         WHERE a.Extencion = "java" AND
           a.Date >= date('2012-04-08') AND
           a.Date < date('2012-04-15')
       GROUP BY a.Name ) AS Previous
    WHERE
       Previous.Name = Cur.Name
       Cur.Extencion = "java" AND
       Cur.Date >= date('2012-04-15') AND
       Cur.Date < date('2012-04-22')
   GROUP BY Cur.Name
```

and it says "Query Error: near "Cur": syntax error Unable to execute statement"
I don't know, can it be that the query is not executable because SQLite does not support Nested Queries?

Anyway, the Table Change has the following form

```
      Author | Path | Extencion | Name | Date | Added | Removed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you spelled `DISTINCT` wrong in this line:

```
COUNT(DISTICT(a.Author)) AS authLast  -- change to DISTINCT
```

Also have you tried your query this way:

```
SELECT Cur.Name, 
  SUM(Cur.Added+Cur.Removed) AS Lines, 
  COUNT(DISTINCT(Cur.Author)) AS authCurrent,
  Previous.authLast AS totCurrent
FROM Change AS Cur
LEFT JOIN 
( 
  SELECT a.Name, COUNT(DISTINCT(a.Author)) AS authLast
  FROM Change AS a
  WHERE a.Extencion = "java" AND
    a.Date >= date('2012-04-08') AND
    a.Date < date('2012-04-15')
  GROUP BY a.Name
) AS Previous
  ON Previous.Name = Cur.Name
WHERE 
       Cur.Extencion = "java" AND
       Cur.Date >= date('2012-04-15') AND
       Cur.Date < date('2012-04-22')
GROUP BY Cur.Name, Previous.authLast
```

Comment: Yes, I misspelt copying it onto the html form, but the query on the database was correctly spelt

Comment: @user1384636 did you try running the version of the query I posted?